# Skip loop when VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a fool-proof tool to report results at my place of work. In order to do this the macro needs to accept .csv files which will be processed by the macro. No problems so far. I got it working as I intended, maybe not completely according to VBA programmers' standards, but working.

However there is one point I struggle with at the moment. Column A and E need to be aligned as this will subsequent processing of results easier for colleagues when using the macro.

There are 3 different scenarios possible of which i got two working.

1. 2 sets of results need to be aligned on the same row (column A and E are (partially filled) (Macro working)
2. 1 set of results alignment not needed as only column A is filled (Macro working)
3. 1 set of results alignment not needed as only column E should be filled (Macro not working)

Column A and E are fixed for the specific results I want to allocate to those columns.

I get a runtime error 1004 'no cells were found', please see below the code I have been using.

```
Sub Report()


Dim csvFileName As Variant
Dim destCell As Range
Dim rdata As Worksheet
Dim Test1Test2reportxl As Workbook
Dim tTest2 As Worksheet
Dim tTest1 As Worksheet

For Each aSheet In Worksheets

Set Test1Test2reportxl = ThisWorkbook
'Hide sheet
' Set Generate = Sheets("Generate")
' Generate.Visible = False


'Delete previous sheets with same name
Select Case aSheet.Name

    Case "rdata"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        aSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Case "Test1Test2report"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        aSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Case "tTest2"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        aSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Case "tTest1"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        aSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True



    Case "TitlePage"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        aSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Add new Test1Test2report and rdata sheet

Next

Dim wb12 As Workbook
Dim ws12 As Worksheet, wsNEW As Worksheet
Dim Test1Test2report As String

'checking if sheet already exists in workbook
Set wb12 = ActiveWorkbook

For Each ws12 In wb12.Worksheets
    If ws12.Name = "Test1Test2report" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next ws12

Sheets("Template").Visible = True

Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) 'move to end

Set wsNEW = ActiveSheet

wsNEW.Name = "Test1Test2report"

Sheets("Template").Visible = False

'MsgBox ("Working so far!")
'new sheet required



Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "rdata"
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "tTest2"
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "tTest1"

 'Import .csv file data

Set destCell = Worksheets("rdata").Cells(Rows.Count, 
"A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)      'CHANGE SHEET NAME
ChDrive "H:\"
    ChDir "H:\Virology Shared Documents\Artus Test1 PCR results\CSV 
 Test1Test2 PCR"
csvFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="CSV Files 
(*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Select a CSV File", MultiSelect:=False)
    If csvFileName = False Then


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("rdata").Delete
    Worksheets("tTest2").Delete
    Worksheets("tTest1").Delete
    Worksheets("Test1Test2report").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    MsgBox "File select was stopped, because you did not select the right 
    file type :-(, please select the right CSV file to proceed!"

    Exit Sub

End If

With destCell.Parent.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & csvFileName, 
Destination:=destCell)
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

destCell.Parent.QueryTables(1).Delete

' Hide columns in rdata sheet

Set rdata = Sheets("rdata")

Range("D:D, H:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
rdata.Visible = True

' Add headers to Test1Test2report sheet

Sheets("Generate").Range("A1:D1").Copy Sheets("tTest1").Range("A1:D1")
Sheets("Generate").Range("A2:D2").Copy Sheets("tTest2").Range("A1:D1")
Sheets("Generate").Range("A4:I4").Copy 
Sheets("Test1Test2report").Range("A1:I1")

    'Test1 data selection and copy to tTest1 sheet

Sheets("rdata").Select

On Error GoTo Test2

If Cells.Find(What:="range test 1)", _
After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False).Activate Then

ActiveCell.Offset(3, 1).Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("tTest1").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("rdata").Select
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("tTest1").Select
Range("D2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End If

Sheets("rdata").Select

On Error GoTo Test2

If Cells.Find(What:="2nd range test 1)", _
After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False).Activate Then

ActiveCell.Offset(3, 1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("tTest1").Select
Range("C2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("rdata").Select
Selection.Offset(0, 3).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("tTest1").Select
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste



End If

 'Test2 data selection and copy to tTest2 sheet


Sheets("rdata").Select

   Test2:

On Error GoTo SheetSelect

If Cells.Find(What:="range test 2)", _
After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False).Activate Then

ActiveCell.Offset(3, 1).Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("tTest2").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("rdata").Select
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("tTest2").Select
Range("D2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End If


Sheets("rdata").Select

On Error GoTo SheetSelect

If Cells.Find(What:=2nd range test 2)", _
After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False).Activate Then

ActiveCell.Offset(3, 1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("tTest2").Select
Range("C2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("rdata").Select
Selection.Offset(0, 3).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("tTest2").Select
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End If

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("rdata").Delete
    Worksheets("tTest2").Delete
    Worksheets("tTest1").Delete
    Worksheets("Test1Test2report").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    MsgBox "You did not select a Test1/Test2 PCR .csv file, please try 
    again!"

End If

Resume

    ' Select data tTest1/tTest2 and copy to Test1Test2report sheet

SheetSelect:

Sheets("tTest1").Select

With Worksheets("tTest1")
lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
.Range("A2:D" & lastrow).Select

Selection.Copy

Sheets("Test1Test2report").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End With

Sheets("tTest2").Select

With Worksheets("tTest2")
lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
.Range("A2:D" & lastrow).Select

Selection.Copy

Sheets("Test1Test2report").Select
Range("E2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End With

 'Hide data sheets

'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Set tTest1 = Sheets("tTest1")
'tTest1.Visible = False

'Set tTest2 = Sheets("tTest2")
'tTest2.Visible = False

'Set rdata = Sheets("rdata")
'rdata.Visible = False

'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Summary:   Align codes in columns C and D removing all D values not in C
Dim i As Long, lr As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     'Last row with data in column F
lr = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Sort both section so numbers are ascending in E and F
Columns("A:D").Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
Columns("E:H").Sort Key1:=Range("E2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

  'line up remaining items so A lines up with E

i = 2
Do
    If Cells(i, "A") > Cells(i, "E") And Cells(i, "E") > "" Then
        Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, 4).Insert xlShiftDown
    ElseIf Cells(i, "A") < Cells(i, "E") And Cells(i, "A") > "" Then
        Cells(i, "E").Resize(1, 4).Insert xlShiftDown
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop Until Cells(i, "A") = "" And Cells(i, "E") = ""
    With Intersect(Columns("A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    .Replace "QS*", "#N/A", xlPart
    On Error Resume Next
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    End With
```

`.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete` is causing the error and Google has not been so kind so far to help me to work out an appropriate answer for this.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add: On Error GoTo ErrorHandler1 does not seem to work

Comment: It's difficult or impossible to troubleshoot an issue without all of the related code (and example data, usually). I don't know which line you're getting the error on, what's in any of the cells, or the values of the variables -- all of which could be clues at to where your bug lies.  If I had to guess based on common mistakes, I'd guess that `i` is zero when this loop starts, and if so, you should set it to a starting value (ie, `i=1`) before the loop starts (since there is no "row zero'.)

Comment: Don't worry. As soon as you have fool-proof code, they'll invent a better fool!

Comment: I see `On Error GoTo ResumeReporting`. Where is `ResumeReporting` in your code? With error handling in VBA, you have to have a `Resume` statement before the code will start "catching" errors again, instead of breaking.

Comment: The `On Error GoTo resumeReporting` is not necessary, sorry I posted the wrong bit of code, I am trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a comment first but had more to say than comment would allow.

Are you sure you mean `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors)` and not `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)` ?  Also might simply want to check to make sure the specialcell intersect is not nothing before attempting to delete it.

I get 1004 error with `xlCelltypeConstants` but `xlCellTypeFormulas` works for me if I put `=na()` in one of the intersecting cells.

```
If Not Intersect(Columns("A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors) Is Nothing Then
    Intersect(Columns("A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```